# What is the equivalent of this binary in mantissa exponent form in denary

Tags: binary, twos-complement

The following mantissa and exponents are represented in twos complement form using 8bits each.

```
Mantissa: 10010000
Exponent: 00000001
```

This is how I tried it,

```
1.0010000 x 2^1
10.010000
```

Converting this decimal point binary to denary:

-2.25

But the answer is supposed to be -1.75, what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to fix the mantissa because it is negative

so the twos compliment is (10010000 xor 11111111) + 1 = 01110000

an u need a binary point so 0.1110000

an the exponenet is just 1 so you double it and jus shift it left so 1.11

an thats binary 1 plus a half pls a quater = 1.75

and negate it again so -1.75